# Jest Enzyme test fails with undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

In the code below I am using React, Jest and Enzyme to confirm that the props passed into the component have a known value. The component under test consists of controlled INPUT elements.  When I change one of the tested values to FAIL the test the Received value comes back as undefined instead of the incorrect value. I am at a loss as to why. Am I testing the input elements value incorrectly?

```
import React from "react"
import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';
import { MyAddressForm } from "../components/addressForm"

const testText = "fieldValue"

const testObject = {
  firstName: {testText},
  lastName: 'Smith'
}

const wrapper = shallow(<MyAddressForm shipTo={testObject}  />)

var fields = []

for (var field in testObject) {
  if (testObject.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
    fields.push(field)
  }
}

var theTest = (fieldName) => {
  let selector = `input[name="${fieldName}"]`
  expect(wrapper.find(selector).prop('value').text).toEqual(testText)
}

test.each(fields)(
  '%s',
  fieldName => theTest(fieldName)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because firstName is being set to an object, not the value of testText!

The correct test function should be:

```
var theTest = (fieldName) => {
  let selector = `input[name="${fieldName}"]`
  expect(wrapper.find(selector).prop('value')).toEqual(testText)
}
```